# Can I save a style with a SVG marker in the database in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3, svg, style-manager

QGIS 3.2, Mac OS 10.13.5.

I have started using some svg markers in my style but now find the option to save it to a database has gone.  Is it possible to save styles with svg in a postgis database like other styles?  I really want all the data associated with the project in the database.